# .htacces rewrite

Tags: url-rewriting

I'm sure there an answer already, but I am unable to formulate my query in short manner.

So here is a question:

I have a PHP app that physically sits in http://www.mydomain.com/demo/
The entire PHP code have all links as `<a href="/index.php">Home</a>` or `<img src="/logo.png">`, etc.

So all refers to the root dir and it's complicate to change the code as the same app have to work from the root folder as well for another client.
I'm sure there is an elegant way to use rewrite rule in .htaccess which I don't really know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in the htacess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/demo%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/demo%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /demo/$1 [L]
```

If you actually need to redirect the browser, replace the `[L]` with `[L,R=301]`.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply, but its not working. I'm getting 404 error for everything :-/